# Haskell saferead of file

Tags: haskell, io

I am attempting to write a simple Haskell function that reads a files contents, if the file exists, and does nothing otherwise.

```
safeRead :: String -> IO ()
safeRead path = readFile path `catch` handleExists
  where handleExists e
    | isDoesNotExistError e = return ()
    | otherwise = throwIO e
```

This, however, fails with: `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`

Why? I've double checked the indentation several times and all seems fine by me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors.

One, as Daniel Sanchez pointed out, is that you're missing an `=` after `otherwise`.

The other is that the cases of `handleExists` must be indented more than the function name, not the `where`. In other words, move the two `|` to the right beyond the `h` of `handleExists`.

Demo: http://goo.gl/EY2c7o

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on indentation of `|`, now I know :) Also thanks for the "jsfiddle of haskell" link. That'll come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `=` after otherwise:

```
safeRead :: String -> IO ()
safeRead path = readFile path `catch` handleExists
    where handleExists e
            | isDoesNotExistError e = return ()
            | otherwise = throwIO e
```

As Sebastian said, the '|' must be pass the `handleExists` `h`.

Comment: while this is obviously true (thank you for taking the time to point it out!) this does not cause my error message to go away (or even change). To avoid confusion going forward I've edited my question to fix the syntax

Comment: let me proppercheck then